# Create Line inside the lake in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, network-analyst

I am trying to find shorthest path between multiple points. I am using new route under Network Analyst in ArcMap.

But, if there is no road between points due to lake or sea, how can I find shortest path between multiple points? For instance, in the picture below, between point(2) and point (11), there is a lake.

Perhaps, I can create line inside the lakes by using ArcMap. Do you have any suggestion how can I do this ?

[image]

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Network Analyst operates over a ***network***. Spatial Analyst operates over continuous cost surfaces, but these support infinite cost cells which prevent their allocation.

Comment: If there is a legitimate ferry route or bridge you're missing then by all means add that to your network to find the shortest route, if there is not then I would suggest there is no way to cross the lake or sea by vehicle and not to join the routes or you will be returning false positives.